# empty() behavior

Tags: php, properties

Maybe I'm asking a stupid question, but I can't understand this behavior:

```
<?php
    $this->meeting->google_id = 'test';
    $test = $this->meeting->google_id;
    var_dump(empty($test));
    var_dump(empty($this->meeting));
    var_dump(empty($this->meeting->google_id));
?>
```

gives output:

```
bool(false) bool(false) bool(true)
```

Why the result of `empty($this->meeting->google_id);` is true? And how should I check this property then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#93117

Basically, PHP [magic methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) resulting in unexpected behavior.

You can read/write to virtual members in a class if the class has a special `__get` magic method. The **actual** value, however, cannot be checked by the `__isset` magic method (which is what `empty` uses), because it's not an explicit member of the class.

Comment: In case you didn't finish reading (which some people have a tendency not to do): you can always write your own `__isset` method, which the same post most courteously provides. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the __isset magic method... clearly I never finished reading the magic methods page past __get, __set and __call ;-)